# How to instantly change the visibility property of child if it has a transition

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions, visibility

I have this html-markup. I make a button with class "open-window", it opens a pop-up window. This window can be closed by pressed button with class "close-window", and when you hover to this button it's background changed with time. After you click on this button, window became invisible, but button still visible for 0.4s (it's transition).

How to hide this button instantly after click and not delete it's background change?

```
<h3>Block title</h3>
<p>
    Block text.Block text.Block text.Block text.Block text.Block text.
</p>
<button class="open-window">Learn more</button>

<div class="window hidden">
    <button class="close-window">
        <span>×</span>
    </button>
    <h3>Block2 title</h3>
    <p>
        Block2 text.Block2 text.Block2 text.Block2 text.Block2 text.
    </p>
    <a href="" class="window-button">
        <button>Go to somewhere</button>
    </a>
    </div>
</div>
<style> 
.hidden{
    visibility: hidden;
}
.window{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 250px;
    background: lightgray;
    position: fixed;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    border-radius: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
}
.close-window {
    position: fixed;
    background: green;
    right: 20px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border: black solid;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.close-window:hover{
    background: blue;
    transition: 0.4s;
}
</style>
<script>
    let openButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('open-window');
    let closeButtons = document.getElementsByClassName('close-window');

    for (let i = 0; i < openButtons.length; i++) {
        openButtons[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            openButtons[i].nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hidden");
        })
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < closeButtons.length; i++) {
        closeButtons[i].addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            closeButtons[i].parentElement.classList.add("hidden");
        })
    }
</script>
```

I'm not sure about using visability here, but idk why display:none not working here. If i set display:none to class "hidden", a pop-up window is visible after a page is loaded and can not be closed.

Comment: Don't transition _all_ properties, but only the background?

Comment: Oof, thank you, it was so easy but i couldn't figure it out. How to rate you comment as solution?

Comment: Comments can only be upvoted, but not marked as an accepted solution. I added a full answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `transition: 0.4s;` you are applying a transition to *all* transitionable properties that undergo a change in value - and `visibility` is one of them.

The most easy fix here in this instance would probably be, that you just specify which property you want to transition explicitly,

```
transition: background 0.4s;
```

Then the change of the `visibility` property can apply right away.